# Select ALL TableView Rows Programmatically Using selectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I'm trying to programmatically select all rows in my tableview using the following code:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:myTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! myTableViewCell

     cell.accessoryType = .None

    if allJobsSelected {

        let bgColorView = UIView()
        bgColorView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 250/255, green: 182/255, blue: 17/255, alpha: 1)
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 250/255, green: 182/255, blue: 17/255, alpha: 1)
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgColorView
        cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
        cell.highlighted = false

        cell.selected = true
        //  cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
        self.tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None)
        self.tableView(self.tableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)

    }

    var job: Jobs!

    job = jobs[UInt(indexPath.row)] as! Jobs

    cell.reports2JobTitle.text = job.jobTitle


    return cell
}

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true

    if let cell:myTableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? myTableViewCell {

        let bgColorView = UIView()
        bgColorView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 250/255, green: 182/255, blue: 17/255, alpha: 1)
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 250/255, green: 182/255, blue: 17/255, alpha: 1)
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgColorView
        cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
        cell.highlighted = false
        self.tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Bottom)

    }


}
```

My issue is that only the rows that have been dequeued are added to my table's data model when I segue to the next viewcontroller. In order to add all the rows to my table's data model I have to manually scroll through the whole table. How can I change this so all the selected rows are added to my table's data model without having to scroll through the whole table?

What I cannot understand is that after all my rows are selected I then loop through my indexPaths as follows but not all of the indexPaths are added unless I first scroll through the entire table.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

    if (segue.identifier == "reportsDisplay") {
        let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! ReportsDisplayViewController

        var selectedJob : Jobs!

        if let indexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {


            for i in 0 ..< indexPaths.count {

                let thisPath = indexPaths[i]



                selectedJob = jobs[UInt(thisPath.row)] as! Jobs



                let jobTitle = selectedJob.jobTitle
                let id = selectedJob.identifier



                jobsToReport.append(jobTitle)
                jobsID.append(id)



            }


        }

        controller.reportedJobs = jobsToReport
        controller.idOfJobs = jobsID

    }


}
```

Comment: It's only string data in my model. I think I can achieve this by using a workaround by having an array of tuples, i.e. the job title and a bool to indicate if that particular job was selected or not. I just feel that there must be a more elegant way to achieve this.

Comment: **Never ever** call delegate methods containing `will`, `should` and `did` by yourself. They are exclusively called by the framework. (A rare exception is KVO's `will/didChangeValueForKey:`)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

At the time `allJobsSelected` becomes true, you need to call the `UITableView` method `selectRowAtIndexPath(_:animated:scrollPosition:)` for each row of your table.  In my case, I attached this functionality to the right bar button item which I named `Select All`.  Calling this from `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is surely not the right place.

```
@IBAction func doSelectAll(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let totalRows = tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(0)
    for row in 0..<totalRows {
        tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: row, inSection: 0), animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None)
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right, I do have gaps in my knowledge. I have added my prepareForSegue function to illustrate. What I don't understand is that within my prepareForSegue function I loop through my indexPaths and I seem to have to make sure that the cell has been dequeued before it is added to my data model. There must be a cleaner method of all my selected cells getting added without me having to manually scroll through the table.

Comment: It's not clear from your code when `allJobsSelected` becomes true, but at the time that happens, you should call `selectRowAtIndexPath` for every row of your table.  That will mark the row selected.  It is not necessary to scroll to the row or load the data.

Answer (score 28):

For **Swift 3** and answering your question literally, regardless of your code.

```
func selectAllRows() {
    for section in 0..<tableView.numberOfSections {
        for row in 0..<tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: section) {
            tableView.selectRow(at: IndexPath(row: row, section: section), animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to inform the tableview delegate, use this method:

```
func selectAllRows() {
    for section in 0..<tableView.numberOfSections {
        for row in 0..<tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: section) {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: section)
            _ = tableView.delegate?.tableView?(tableView, willSelectRowAt: indexPath)
            tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
            tableView.delegate?.tableView?(tableView, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant - Thank you for the solution!

Answer (score 1):

#### Functional solution (Swift 5.1)

```
extension UITableViewDataSource where Self: UITableView {
  /**
   * Returns all IndexPath's in a table
   * ## Examples:
   * table.indexPaths.forEach {
   *    selectRow(at: $0, animated: true, scrollPosition: .none) // selects all cells
   * }
   */
  public var indexPaths: [IndexPath] {
     return (0..<self.numberOfSections).indices.map { (sectionIndex: Int) -> [IndexPath] in
        (0..<self.numberOfRows(inSection: sectionIndex)).indices.compactMap { (rowIndex: Int) -> IndexPath? in
           IndexPath(row: rowIndex, section: sectionIndex)
        }
        }.flatMap { $0 }
  }
}
```

Comment: Intersecting `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableView` is not a good idea

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for Swift 5.5**

This method can be logically made an extension of `UITableView` and must be called from the main thread:

```
extension UITableView {
    // Must be called from the main thread
    func selectAllRows() {
        let totalRows = self.numberOfRows(inSection: 0)
        for row in 0..<totalRows {
            self.selectRow(at: IndexPath(row: row, section: 0), animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)
        }
    }
}
```

Note: this code is only for the only section