# Selecting every row in TableView including off-screen rows

Tags: swift, uitableview

Right now, I'm able to select all rows visible on the screen, but I want to be able to select all rows in the TableView including off-screen rows.

I've tried the extension here: [programmatically select all cells in tableview so next time they are pressed they call didDeselect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43746664/programmatically-select-all-cells-in-tableview-so-next-time-they-are-pressed-the)

As well as second solution here: [Select ALL TableView Rows Programmatically Using selectRowAtIndexPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38421681/select-all-tableview-rows-programmatically-using-selectrowatindexpath)

Both end with the same results, only visible rows being selected.

My end goal is, when I'm able to select all rows, I can then press my "Acknowledge" button and that retrieves an ID for each row, then sends it to the server, which I'm already able to accomplish, I just need to figure out how to select ALL rows so I can get that list of IDs.

Thanks for the help!

Added Data source structure

```
var dataClassArr = [DataClass]()

struct DataClass: Codable {
    let id: String
}
```

Comment: Wouldn’t it be easier to get all ID’s from the data source (array) instead?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I didn't even think of that! I'll go ahead and give that a shot. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **don't**.

You can't select all cells because they're being reused, which means only enough cells exist.

When the "Acknowledge" button is pressed, you can get the data from your datasource, the one you're consuming to create your `UITableView`.

---

**Note:** If there is a state change when that button is pressed, you should iterate through your datasource and update your objects. And then you `.reloadData()`.

---

Updates based on your question update, this is how you iterate through your datasource.

```swift
        var dataClassArr = [DataClass]()

        var result = [String]()

        dataClassArr.append(DataClass(id: "1"))
        dataClassArr.append(DataClass(id: "42")) // just for example, you should remove those.

        for element in dataClassArr {
            result.append(element.id)
        }

        print(result) // ["1", "42"] -> based on example values.
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll go ahead and give that a shot!

Comment: Hmm, I can't seem to figure out how to access my Codable struct to access all of the IDs. How would I go about doing that? I'll update my question with my struct shortly.

Comment: it's `dataClassArr`, what do you want to send to your backend? You can create a `[String]()` and iterate through `dataClassArr`, appending each id as String.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I want, but how would I iterate through dataClassArr since it's Codable? I found example for structs without Codable, tried those and didn't work.

Comment: Thank you very much! That is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your `UITableView`'s data source is

```
struct Item {
    id: Int
}
var dataSource: [Item] = []
```

You should select all ids from above data source, like so:

```
let result = dataSource.map{ $0.id }
```

If you need to change the user interface to select `UITableViewCell`s, you have to create a new property `isSelected` in your struct, because you **cannot** change selection state of a `UITableViewCell` that is not visible, so begin by adding the new property:

```
struct Item {
    id: Int
    var isSelected = false
}
```

Now you will use above data source to change the selection state, like so

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    private var dataSource = [Item]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Toggle", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(selectAllAction))
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Acknowledge", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(acknowledgeAction))

        self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self
    }

    @objc func selectAllAction() {
        let totalRows = self.dataSource.count
        let isSelectAll = self.dataSource.first(where: { !$0.isSelected }) != nil
        for index in 0..<totalRows {
            self.dataSource[index].isSelected = isSelectAll
        }
        self.tableView.visibleCells.forEach {
            $0.setSelected(isSelectAll, animated: true)
        }
    }

    @objc func acknowledgeAction() {
        let result = self.dataSource.compactMap{ $0.isSelected ? $0.id : nil }
        print(result)

        guard !result.isEmpty else { return }

        // send selected id(s) to the server
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        cell.isSelected = self.dataSource[indexPath.row].isSelected
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.dataSource[indexPath.row].isSelected = true
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.dataSource[indexPath.row].isSelected = false
    }

}
```